# How to prevent the Browser to push a state into the history?

Tags: javascript, browser-history, hashchange

I am currently working on a web site and came across the following problem:

Assume my websites name is `www.mysite.com.` On the first call of the page, my JavaScript checks, whether there are certain parameters in the URL, that are important for the web applications state. Those parameters are for example:

```
lang - language --> lang=1 means German
page - current Page --> page=home means its the homepage
cats - categories --> cats=1,2,3 means that the default categories are 1,2 and 3
```

If you just call www.mysite.com, the script detects, that no parameters are set. It will then set the default parameters. Based on URL modifications with the hashmark, i set the URL to:

```
www.mysite.com/#/page=home&lang=1&cats=12,13,18
```

The real problem about this is, that inside the browser history two states are set. The first is www.mysite.com and the second the complex URL with the parameters.

So imagine I am currently at

```
www.mysite.com/#/page=home&lang=1&cats=12,13,18
```

and press the return button now. The browser brings me to

```
www.mysite.com
```

and then my Javascript detects, that there are no parameters, so it takes me again to

```
www.mysite.com/#/page=home&lang=1&cats=12,13,18
```

How to solve this? Is it possible to manage the history completely manually, so that i could push each state by my JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make the web application just use default values without any hash in the URL?

Comment: what do you mean by default values?

Answer (score -2):

Switch to using [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) to store the parameters with optional fallback to cookies or something.

Then use hashtag only for the states you want to be able to get back to.

Comment: These are all states, I want to get back to.